# Move partitions from first database to second database

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have two databases 
First database with partions in table history:

```
 PARTITION p2019_03_10 VALUES LESS THAN (1552251600) ENGINE = InnoDB,    
 PARTITION p2019_03_11 VALUES LESS THAN (1552338000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

Second database with partions in table history:

```
 PARTITION p2019_03_08 VALUES LESS THAN (1552241600) ENGINE = InnoDB,    
 PARTITION p2019_03_09 VALUES LESS THAN (1552368000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

On both databases the structure of the table history is the same.

How could i make union between the 2 databases and move partions from database 2 to database 1

Answer (score 0):

See [*transportable tablespaces*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tablespace-copying.html).  You will need at least 5.7.4.

If you need help, then provide more information, as found in that link.